# How to send module to an imported ES6 Classe outside of a controller

Tags: node.js, symfony, webpack, bundle

Hello i'm using webpack on symfony.
I've imported some ES6 classes using module.exports like this :

```
module.exports = class Exemple{
 constructor(arg1)
}
```

I need to use a module that i've defined before to call the require including my class in this class without calling the module in the controller .
that would be something like this :

Template.js

---

```
Module.exports = class Template{
Routing.generate(****)
}
```

index.js

---

```
import Routing from '../../../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';
Routing.setRoutingData(routes);
require('../templateManager.js'),(Routing)
```

;

How can i pass Routing to my class to use it in without using Controller

Comment: You seem to have an erroneous `,` after your final `require`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Hello Joey. my bad for the commat. In fact it is the argument that i try to send to my class Exemple . I need to use in it but i don't want to give it to the controller. I wouldlike to use the imported "Routing" as something like a global Variable usable in all my require

Answer (score 0):

Node.js will only export a variable once. So you can initialise something, then export it. And you will receive the same value everywhere.
For your example, you can set up your `Routing` instance then export it, and use that elsewhere.

```
// routing.js
import Routing from '<snip>/router.min.js';

Routing.setRoutingData(routes);
export default Routing;

// Elsewhere
import Routing from './routing';
// Routing is now your pre-initialised instance of Routing

class Template {
    Routing.generate(****)
}

export default Template;
```

Comment: it finally worked ! i used export { Template } in place of module.exports. Thank you